# How to ask, things to bring home, when the get over(empty) at home?

Tags: direct-objects

I am trying to find out right words to express emptiness of things at home, once they get empty after we consume.
For example, milk finished at home, please bring some.
finished mosquito coil bring home.
tomatoes are rotten at home, please bring fresh lot.
Bread is smelling or not good or empty, bring some bread.

Or kind of questions, like "Do we have sugar at home or not? Should we buy?"

Comment: You can something along the lines of "we are out of milk".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We are **out of** milk. Could you **pick up** some from the store?
>
> Are we **out of** milk?  Maybe we should get some while we are at the store?

These are common expressions around my house that can be used for various consumables: *eggs, lettuce, cheese, toothpaste, soap, toilet paper, cat food*, etc.

Slightly more accusatory, you can ask:

> Hey did you **use up** all the milk?

Or for countable nouns:

> Hey did you **finish up the last of the** eggs?

Comment: Is that Ok to say, "The tomotoes from last time have spoiled. Please pick up some fresh ones from store."

Answer (score 2):

Forget the detailed explanations as to why, just make a simple request.

> We urgently need milk, mosquito coils, tomatoes, and bread. Please buy some on
>   your way home.